# Android Fragments - Edit Text Of Another Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

So I have made a simple heating text control app and it all works with permissions and all of that but it uses 2 fragments and inside them are two textboxes which I want to have the same text in -- phone number. I cannot get the edittext in rel2 to be changed by rel1.

Rel 1:

```
package com.danielkern.relswitcher;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

import static android.content.SharedPreferences.*;

/**
 * Created by Daniel Kern on 03/01/2018.
 */

public class Rel1 extends Fragment{
    Button BtnHOFF, BtnHON, BtnHST, saveB;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rel1, container, false);
        final View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rel2, container, false);
        final SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedNo = sharedPref.getString("phoneNo", "07599070551");
        BtnHOFF = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Hoff);
        BtnHON = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Hon);
        BtnHST = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Hstatus);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        saveB = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.saveB);
        ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(savedNo);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), savedNo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        BtnHOFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMsg("#REL1=ON", txtPhoneNo.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        BtnHON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMsg("#REL1=OFF", txtPhoneNo.getText().toString());
                Log.i(getActivity().toString(), "Done!");
            }
        });
        BtnHST.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMsg("#STATUS", txtPhoneNo.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        saveB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sharedPref.edit().putString("phoneNo", txtPhoneNo.getText().toString());
                Log.i("me", "Saved!");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Saved!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ((EditText) view2.findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(txtPhoneNo.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public void sendMsg(String msg, String num){
        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(num, null, msg, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS failed, contact administrator!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Rel 2:

```
package com.danielkern.relswitcher;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Daniel Kern on 03/01/2018.
 */

public class Rel2 extends Fragment {
    Button BtnWOFF, BtnWON, BtnWST, saveB;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rel2, container, false);
        final View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rel1, container, false);
        final SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedNo = sharedPref.getString("phoneNo", "07599070551");
        BtnWOFF = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Woff);
        BtnWON = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Won);
        BtnWST = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Wstatus);
        saveB = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.saveB);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(savedNo);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), savedNo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        BtnWOFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMsg("#REL2=ON", txtPhoneNo.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        BtnWON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMsg("#REL2=OFF", txtPhoneNo.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        BtnWST.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMsg("#STATUS", txtPhoneNo.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        saveB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sharedPref.edit().putString("phoneNo", txtPhoneNo.getText().toString());
                ((EditText) view1.findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(txtPhoneNo.getText().toString());
                Log.d("me", "Saved!");
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public void sendMsg(String msg, String num){
        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(num, null, msg, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS failed, contact administrator!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Rel 1 xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Hon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Heating ON (REL1 OFF)"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Hoff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Hon"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="Heating OFF (REL1 ON)"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Hstatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Hoff"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="STATUS"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
        android:text="Coming Soon!"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="07599070551"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Rel 2 XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Won"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Water ON (REL2 OFF)"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Woff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Won"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="Water OFF (Rel2 On)"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Wstatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Woff"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="STATUS"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
        android:text="Coming Soon!"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:
I would like the edit text in Rel2 to change when I press save in rel1 therefore the phone number boxes will always be the same.
[rel1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9uy4.png)

EDIT 2:
I have fixed the shared prefs issue but I would still like to know if anyone can make the textboxes the same wherether that is on text update or on save button press.

Comment: Please explain a little bit more about what you're trying to do... You want the EditText in Rel2 to update immediately while your typing in the EditText in Rel1?

Comment: Are both the `Fragments` loaded in the `Activity` at the same time?

Comment: I want the EditText in Rel2 to change when I press the save button

Comment: @SaranSankaran Sorry but how do I check this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. Using Interface

Create an interface with a method something like `TextChangeListener` and declare a method `onTextChange(String text)`.

```
interface TextChangeListener{
    void onTextChange(String number);
}
```

Implement the interface in the `HostActivity`

```
class HostActivity extends Activity implements TextChangeListener{
   ...
   void onTextChange(String number){
       secondFragment.updateNumber(number)
   }
   ...
}
```

In FirstFragment call the activity using the implmented interface in the `afterTextChanged()` listener of `TextWatcher`

```
class FirstFragment extends Fragment{
    private TextChangeListener activity;

    @Override
    public onAttach(Context context){
         if(context instanceof TextChangeListener){
              activity = (TextChangeListener) context;
         }
    }

    phNumEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override           
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            activity.onTextChange(s.toString);
        }
        ...
    );

...
}
```

In SecondFragment on receiving the call from activity, update the `EditText` with new data.

```
class SecondFragment extends Fragment{
    ...
    public void updateNumber(String number){
        editText.setText(number);
    }
}
```

2. Using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Use `EventBus` to post an event from `FirstFragment`. The event will contain the data to be populated in `SecondFragment`. The `SecondFragment` will Subscribe to the event and on receiving the event the data will be populate into the `EditText`.

Comment: I'd recommend using an Interface too. I'm still not 100% sure on what OP is trying to accomplish tho.

Comment: The interface answer looks but how can I do this?